# Use Visual Studio 2015 CTP 6 for production?

Tags: visual-studio

Is it possible to use Visual Studio 2015 CTP 6 for a production environment?

Checked VS homepage for info but couldn't find any.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense to me. Visual Studio is an IDE which doesn't make sense in the context of "production environment." Are you asking if it can build production-ready code?

Comment: Do you mean if the CTP version comes with a license which can be used commercially?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible but you do so at your own risk. The [download page](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-2015-downloads-vs.aspx) for **Visual Studio 2015 Preview** says clearly that the software is *not intended for use on production computers, or to create production code*. The relevant text from that page says:

> NOTE Visual Studio 2015 Preview and .NET 4.6 Preview are for testing
>   and feedback purposes only. This release is unsupported and are not
>   intended for use on production computers, or to create production
>   code. We strongly recommend only installing this release in a virtual
>   machine, or on a computer that is available for reformatting.

Answer (score 1):

The rule of thumb is that CTP build usually has no 'Go Live' support and anything can change dramatically.

In a later Beta or RC build, you might read from Visual Studio team blog at MSDN they will announce Go Live support.